# If one proves uniform convergence of a function does that imply convergence in every other $L^p$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, machine-learning, approximation-theory

I was wondering about the truth of the following:

> $$ \text{if} \lim_{n\to \infty} \| f_n - f \|_{\infty,S}=0 \implies \forall p\in \{ 2,3,4,...\}, \lim_{n\to\infty} \| f_n - f \|_{p,S} = 0$$
>
> or at least in $L^2$ norm.

I think this statement is false. The reason is by re-writing the first part:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ \lim_{p \to \infty} \| f_n - f \|_{p,S}  \right] =0 $$

and then reading what it means. It is saying that the as n goes to infinity the limit inside goes to zero only as the limit inside itself has $p$ go to infinity. Thus, my suspicion is that since the limit inside implicitly requires $p$ to grow and grow (for sufficiently large $p$) or "be at infinity already" (since we are talking about the actual limit value). Then means that the outer limit with $n$ is not true with $n$ going to infinity. This is my intuition of why its false, informally because the outer limit is only true when "$p=\infty$".

I bet that a counter example would be the easiest way to prove it. To construct it I tried sort of unraveling what the limit definitions where saying rigorously. I open up the out limit first (i.e. definition using for sufficiently large N...):

$$ \forall \epsilon_n, \exists N': \text{if } n \geq N' \implies | \lim_{p\to \infty} \| f_n - f \|_{p,S} - 0  | < \epsilon_n$$

where $\epsilon_n$ is one symbol denoting the outer limit (i.e. its not a function of $n$, the $n$ denotes its the epsilon for the outer limit).

But then when I tried to open up the second I got confused where the new quantifiers for the inner limit where suppose to go and thus, gave up because I didn't know how to let the statement still be true without writing non-sense. Does someone know how to do this? Maybe this is the wrong way to do it but its what I have...

---

Anyway, I thought it would be nice to put my question in context too since I believe I am not dealing with arbitrary functions. I was reading [the following approximation theory paper in the context of Neural Networks](https://cbmm.mit.edu/publications/why-and-when-can-deep-not-shallow-networks-avoid-curse-dimensionality-review). I am no expert in approximation theory, thus my question. In the paper section 3.1 they have the following sentences:

> Notice, however, that from the point of view of machine learning, the
>   relevant norm is the L2 norm. In this sense, several of our results
>   are stronger than needed.

I guess since the quote says:

> several of our results are stronger than needed.

I assumed that since the authors have convergence results in the sup norm, then it must mean that it somehow automatically implies its true for the truly relevant norm (i.e. the $L^2$ norm) in their machine learning context. Since a stronger statement $A$ implies weaker statements $B$ (check [Why is the definition of stronger statement the way it is in logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560267/why-is-the-definition-of-stronger-statement-the-way-it-is-in-logic)) then it was natural to assume that indeed, the authors where implying that it automatically extended to the $L^2$ norm.

Is that true? Can the results in that paper extend to the relevant loss functions $L^2$ norms in machine learning?

---

As a summary the context of target functions $f$ and the functions used to approximate (i.e. the one that forms the sequence of functions $f_n$) can be found in section 3.1 and 3.2 I believe. The target class $W^n_{m}$ is a smoothness class with the following property:

$$ \| f \|_{\infty} + \sum_{ 1 \leq | k |_1 \leq m}\| D^{k} f \|_{\infty} \leq 1 $$

i.e. all functions of $n$ variables and $m < \infty $ partial derivatives indicated by the multi-integer $k\geq 1$ and $|k|_1$ is the sum of the components of $k$.

These function are approximated with Neural Networks, I believe with smooth activation functions.

Comment: I've never seen this notation before. How is the norm $|\!|f|\!|_{p,S}$ defined?

Comment: @uniquesolution oh really? I thought it was standard since I looked up wikipedia before asking this question (note this is not my field of expertise). The definition is $\| f \|_{\infty,S} = \sup_{x \in S} |f(x)| = \sup \{ |f(x)| : x \in S \}$ in the wikipedia article its the first equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm

Comment: On a set of finite measure, convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in $L^q$ for $q < p$ because of Holder's inequality. In particular convergence in $L^\infty$ implies convergence in every other $L^p$. This is not true on sets of infinite measure; one can find functions converging in $L^1$ that don't converge in $L^\infty$ and those that converge in $L^\infty$ that don't converge in $L^1$. Think of examples where mass escapes to the left/right or escapes to infinity.

Comment: @Nitin what about in the context that I provided? I guess since its Sobolev space and the norms seem to be bounded (the input space is a bounded hypercube $[-1,1]^n$). Then it seems its also bounded in the context of the paper I was reading?

Comment: @Nitin also btw, why is my conceptual explanation of why it should be a false statement incorrect? Where did I go wrong you know?

Comment: @Pinocchio. Wikipedia is not a standard mathematical reference. The definition you mention is absent from the leading 20 texts in functional analysis, for example.

Comment: If $\mu(S) < +\infty$ then the statement is true:

We have $|f - f_n| \le \|f - f_n\|_{\infty, S}$ almost everywhere so:

$$\|f - f_n\|_{p,S}^p = \int_S |f - f_n|\,d\mu \le \int_S \|f - f_n\|_{\infty, S}\,d\mu = \mu(S)\|f - f_n\|_{\infty, S} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

We conclude $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} f$ in $L^p(S)$.

Comment: Otherwise, consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda $ and the sequence $f_n = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{\left[2^n, 2^{n+1}\right]}$. We have:

$$\|f_n\|_{\infty, \mathbb{R}} = \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

so $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

However:

$$\|f_n\|_{p, \mathbb{R}}^p = \int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}n \,d\lambda = \frac{2^n}{n}$$ 

which does not converge to $0$ so $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying measure space $X$ has infinite measure then consider $f_n(x) := 1/n \mathbb 1_{A_n}$ where $A_n$ is a set with measure tending to infinity faster than $n$. $f_n \to 0$ in $L^\infty(X)$ but there is no hope for any $L^p$ convergence, $p\in[1,\infty)$.

If the underlying measure space $X$ has finite measure then note that
$$ \| f \|_{L^p(X)}^p = \int_X |f|^p ≤ \|f\|^p_{L^\infty(X)} |X| $$
so convergence in $L^\infty$ implies convergence in any $L^p$, $p\in [1,\infty]$.

Its true that for functions $f\in \bigcap_{p\in[1,\infty]}L^p$, $\|f\|_{L^\infty} = \lim_{p\to\infty} \|f\|_{L^p}$ but this is a restrictive assumption on $f$. For example, without extra information, its possible that none of the $L^p$ spaces are contained in another.

Comment: what Im still trying to digest is if the proof for sup norm in the paper I linked does indeed imply it holds for every other $L^p$ norm specially $L^2$.

Comment: @Pinocchio It does, the space considered there is $I^n=[-1,1]^n$ which is finite measure. By the way, in more standard PDE references, the space this paper calls $W^n_m$ would be called $W^{m,\infty}(I^n)$.